# How to translate "hibernate"? (in the biological / zoological meaning)

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, biology

Using the definition [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation)

> **Hibernation** is a state of inactivity and [metabolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolism) depression in [endotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endotherm). Hibernation refers to a season of [heterothermy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterothermy) characterized by low body-temperature, slow breathing and heart-rate, and low [metabolic rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_rate). It most commonly occurs during [winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter) months.

More colloquially expressed, it's a state some animals enter to save energy (usually during winter) by sleeping more or less the whole time or at least being at rest more than usually.

The Esperanto word for this seems to be **"[vintra dormo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintra_dormo)"**, mirroring e.g. the German ["Winterschlaf"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winterschlaf).

The [verb "hibernate"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hibernate#Verb) means to spend time in hibernation. Not all languages can express this in a single word. E.g. in German one would say "Winterschlaf halten".

**How would "to hibernate" be expressed in Esperanto?**

Would it be "vintre dormi" or something like that? If so, how would one distinguish from just normal "sleeping in Winter" unrelated to hibernation, like in "I don't sleep well in winter, because by bedroom is always either too cold or too warm."?

Google translate suggests "hiberni", but I don't quite trust that, as I couldn't find it in any Esperanto dictionary.

Comment: _vintrodormi_, according to JC Wells.

Answer (score 2):

Oni povas uzi *travintri*. Jen difino de [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#travintri) kaj [Revo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vintr.html#vintr.tra0i). Mi ĝin ŝatas ĉar ĝi priskribas la celon, ne la rimedon, do ĝi ankaŭ taŭgas por plantoj ekzemple.